# Validation error from model on ajax call asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

How i can show validation error on ajax call because it is not showing error on ajax call.I have attached my code please review it and tell me where i am wrong.i am not using strongly model binding. without ajax call it is showing model error but i want to show model error with ajax call.

**Model**

```
public class Feedback
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Comment field is required")]
    [Display(Name = "Comment")]
    [MaxLength(1000, ErrorMessage = "Comment Cannot Be Longer Than 1000 Characters")]
    public string CommentText { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Nme field is required")]
    [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Name Cannot Be Longer Than 100 Characters")]

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email field is required")]
    [MaxLength(150, ErrorMessage = "Email cannot be longer than 150 characters")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z-._0-9]+@[a-zA-Z]+\.[A-Za-z]+$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult feedbackAndReview(Feedback feed)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //add to database

    }
    return View();
}
```

**view**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <textarea class="form-control" id="CommentText" style="margin-bottom:10px;max-width:100%; height:139px;" placeholder="Your thoughts"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name" id="Name" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="email" placeholder="Enter Valid Email Address" class="form-control" id="Email" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="button" onclick="submitReviewForm()" class="reviewBtn">POST REVIEW</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Ajax Code**

```
function submitReviewForm()
{
    var comment = $("#CommentText").val();
    var name = $("#Name").val();
    var email = $("#Email").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/Account/feedbackAndReview',
        data: {'CommentText' : comment , 'Name' : name , 'Email' : email },
        success : function (data)
        {

        }

    })
}
```

Comment: Add an error handler in you ajax call

Comment: i have no idea can you help me how to add it will be good ?

Comment: This is one of the limitations with MVC and why languages like Angular are used. When you do an ajax call in MVC, you lose your model capabilities including the use of your data annotations on the model Feedback. @dcg comment is the way to go, but if you're using jQuery unobtrusive then you'll have to manually fire the validation inside your failed callback method.

Comment: @user10728126 yeah i am using  jQuery unobtrusive but it is not showing error on ajax call so how i can manually fire the validations ?

Comment: Are you using .cshtml for your view or just a standard html file for use with Angular? If you have a .cshtml file, jQuery unobtrusive will work but you need to use ValidationMessageFor in your view. For example if you placed <div>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CommentText)</div> below your textarea. For this to work you will also need to have your model declared at the top of your CSHTML.

Comment: $('#myFormId').valid(); should fire all annotations. I believe it returns a value too

Comment: @user10728126 i am not using form, directly getting value with javascript and than passing those values to ajax action as you can seen in my ajax code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a form and a bound model to make it easier!

```
@model Feedback
<head
 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<form id="myform" method="post">
   <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
    <textarea class="form-control" id="CommentText" style="margin-bottom:10px;max-width:100%; height:139px;" placeholder="Your thoughts"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name" id="Name" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" placeholder="Enter Valid Email Address" class="form-control" id="Email" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="btnSubmit" class="reviewBtn">POST REVIEW</button>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </form>


$('#myform').on('submit', function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

   var ok = $(this).valid();

  if (ok) {

      var comment = $("#CommentText").val();
      var name = $("#Name").val();
      var email = $("#Email").val();

      $.ajax({
         type: 'post',
         url: '/Account/feedbackAndReview',
         data: {'CommentText' : comment , 'Name' : name , 'Email' : email },
         success : function (data)
         {
         }
     })
   }
}
```

Comment: one thing to know that `e.preventDefault();` is preventing form to reloading ? while submit.

Comment: yw! It's preventing the default behavior from occurring. So technically in a way yes, it's how to get the ajax call to fire instead of the full postback with the form. Keep in mind, inside your callback success function, you lose the model binding capabilities. So If you want to bind anything back to those inputs in your form, you'll have to do it manually with an html append.